# java.lang.ClassCastException - Same Object - Two classes, why?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, casting

I'm working in the android Studio,2.1.2.

I have a mysterious cast Exception between two activity.

In the First Activity i have this ArrayList:

```
 ArrayList<riparazione> nuovo = notizia.get_Elenco();
```

I insert the arraylist ( parcellable ) in a bundle for  send at another activity:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(prenota_mostra_cellulari.this, prenota_mostra_dettagli.class);

                Bundle spedizione = new Bundle();
                    spedizione.putString("Nome",notizia.get_Marca());
                    spedizione.putString("Foto",notizia.get_Foto());
                    spedizione.putString("Marca",notizia.get_Nome());
                    spedizione.putParcelableArrayList("Riparazioni",nuovo);

                   intent.putExtras(spedizione);
                   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

In second activity i use this for recover ArrayList

```
  ArrayList<riparazione> nuovo = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
        dati_cel = intent.getExtras();
        nuovo = dati_cel.getParcelableArrayList("Riparazioni");

        Log.d("Dati", String.valueOf(dati_cel.size()));
        Log.d("Dati arraylist", String.valueOf(dati_cel.size()));
        riparazione dads = nuovo.get(9);
    }
```

NOW in line of `riparazione dads = nuovo.get(9);`

i get an Cast error :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.luca.ireplace.orario cannot be cast to com.example.luca.ireplace.riparazione

I have tried everything , with and without Bundle for sending, the class output end output are the same why this casting? And How do I solve??

Thanks for any Help

Comment: Looks like a class loader Problem. Same class on different classloader get this problem

Answer (score 1):

The error is not in the code that you posted. Remember that Lists (and generics generally) suffer from type erasure. That means that even though you declared nuovo as `ArrayList<riparazione>`, Java will not check at runtime whether you are adding `riparazione`s to the list or whether the list actually contains `riparazione`s when you pass it.

You somehow inserted an `orario` into the list. The error occurs here:

```
riparazione dads = nuovo.get(9);
```

We have no idea how the `nuovo` list originally gets constructed, but the error is obviously not in the code that you posted.

Comment: if i add a object riparazione : riparazione a1 = new riparazione(Strig a,String b, String c,String d) at nuovo. the adding is ok.

Comment: Yes, but somehow the `nuovo` list got an `orario` in it. I don't know how it got there, but it got there (that's what the error is telling you).